# Calling an action within the same controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following works, but I am wondering if there is a better way? On a index page we are listing widgets. You can edit each widget in its show view, but to increase efficiency we would like to give users the ability to do bulk actions from the index page by adding a check box to each widget, then gather up the selected widgets, pass those along to the controller and 'do stuff' to them from the controller in one fail swoop. Here is the code...

## view

```
<%= form_tag bulk_change_widgets_path(method: :post) do %>  
      <%- @widgets.each do |image| -%>
        ....
              <%= check_box_tag 'selected_widget_ids[]', widget.id -%>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <%- end -%>
      <%= submit_tag %> 
    <%- end -%>
```

## controller

```
action_one
  @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
...
end

action_two
  @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
...
end

def bulk_change_widgets
    selected_widgets = params[:selected_widget_ids]

    selected_widgets.each do |widget|
      params[:id] = widget
      action_one
      action_tow
    end

    redirect_to widgets_path
  end
```

The existing structure of action_one/two needs to stay in place to accommodate the instance methods called from the show page for each widget. However, something doesn't *feel* right about calling action_one/two this way from within the same controller. Is there a better, or a *Rails Way* to do this?

Comment: move the code to model, then make it one method there so you can call it with @widget.update_both

Comment: I concur with @icemelt ... put the common code in a private method in the controller, and call that method both from `action_one` and from `buk_change_widgets` and if it can legitimately be said to be a model method, put it in the model instead... `widget.do_the_one_action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be more efficient. Instead of multiple queries to get widgets individually, do a single query to get them all and use this list to iterate. If it's too many widget ids and loading them in memory is an issue (I don't think this is the case), you can do a [find_each](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each)

```
  def bulk_change_widgets
    selected_widgets = Widget.where(:id => params[:selected_widget_ids])

    selected_widgets.each do |widget|
      widget.take_action
    end

    redirect_to widgets_path
  end
```

And, like the comments said, move the method to the Widget class (fat models, thin controllers).